# Landing Page with Top Menu Navigation

Tags: cms, layered-navigation

I recently starting working with Magento for a project and it has a lot of content. The old website uses CMS pages for non product content. Then there is a category in the layered navigation, and then does a 301 redirect to the CMS page. Since I am building a new website, should I use the layered navigation and the associate a static block instead and not use a CMS page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean, you goes right direction.Create a cms block and Assign that to category and make Display: `Only Block from Display` Setting  Tab .

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to make sure that was the proper way to do it.